# Strange behavior when adding a string with spaces to ZooKeeper

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

With ZK 3.4.5 and zkCli.sh I get the following:

```
./zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] create /test 100
Created /test
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] create /test/spacesString "this string has spaces in it"
Created /test/spacesString
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 2] get /test/spacesString
"this
cZxid = 0x9c220
ctime = Wed Mar 11 06:46:10 EDT 2015
mZxid = 0x9c220
mtime = Wed Mar 11 06:46:10 EDT 2015
[deleted rest of output here]
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 3] set /test/spacesString "new value"
Command failed: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "value""
```

I tried this approach because of [here](http://zookeeper-user.578899.n2.nabble.com/newbie-question-how-to-set-a-znode-value-to-a-string-quot-this-is-a-string-quot-instead-of-a-single--td7579915.html).
From that, I gathered that what I tried should work.  Two questions:

1. Why doesn't the first string with spaces get created properly?
2. Why does the subsequent 'set' throw NumberFormatException?

Comment: From what I have read around, you cannot add string values with spaces via the command line tool for Zookeeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it didn't work is because the command parser used spaces to tokenize the input and didn't handle strings properly.  This was addressed in:

[ZOOKEEPER-1853](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1853) - "zkCli.sh can't issue a CREATE command containing spaces in the data".

According to the JIRA, the fix should be in 3.4.7, 3.5.2 and 3.6.0.

Comment: While this was OBE and I don't have a way to verify any longer - you get the credit for answering such an old question!